# How to validate data in onCreateUser without losing the form data?

Tags: meteor, verification, accounts

I'm writing an Appliction using Meteor. In this App I want to implement a server-side validation of the user data using Accounts.onCreateUser. There is some data passed which can only be verified on the server side.

At client side I call:

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var attributes = {
            username: $("#inputUsername").val(),
            password: $("#inputPassword").val(),
            confirmation: $("inputConfirmation").val(),
            email: $("#inputEmail").val(),
            ...
        };

        Accounts.createUser(attributes, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throwError(err);
            } else {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And on the server side:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if(!verifyData(options))
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Wrong input");
    return user;
});
```

After the server side verification fails, all form data is lost. What is the best way to keep the data?

Comment: What is the reason why you implemented server side validation ? If you do nothing that is not possible on the client I would strongly advise to just validate on the client-side. Could you maybe also elaborate more on what it is that you want to do with the data once the validation doesn't pass?

Comment: An example could be a captcha, which has to be verified by the server or data which has to be checked against the database. When the validation don't pass the values of the input fields should be still there.

Comment: What is happening inside your `throwError` function?

Comment: @Kishin everything needs to be validated on the server side... Otherwise a user could open their browser console and send bad data to the server directly with a method call.

Comment: throwError only inserts the error message into an Meteor.Collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and reproduced your code on a [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/pLMhmQpm4LHzv57f7/Server-side%20Form%20Validation) and from what I can tell, the form data does still persist. You just need to access it via the `attributes` variable in the client-side.

There may be something I am missing, but i took what you posted above and put it in there.

Comment: Thank. Your code on Meteorpad shows that everthing works as expected. I did a mistake using the iron:router which caused a reload.